# Printing skips the first line

Tags: python, list, line, skip

```
file1=open("filex.txt","r")
line=file1.readline()
for line in file1:
   print(line,end="")
```

So this prints out all the lines in the file, except the first line for some reason, help me out please!

Comment: `line = file1.readline()` ?

Comment: `line=file1.readline()`  - You skipped the first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the line:

```
line=file1.readline()
```

which reads the first line and thus moves the file pointer past the first line before you start your actual line-by-line iteration. Generally, a file handle as returned by `open(...)` is an iterator that produces each line only once. You can, however, move it back to beginning by:

```
file1.seek(0)
```

Comment: Aww, you beat me to it

Comment: this alone will not solve the problem. A file itself cannot be iterated through, the lines need to be iterated. That's what `file.readlines()` is for.

Comment: @sam-pyt It won't? I think it does!

Comment: wait. yeah nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

`file1` is an iterator that can yield each of its elements (lines, to be precise) only once - then it is empty.

By calling `readline` once before iterating over the rest of the lines, the first line has already been read.

Demo:

```
>>> fake_file = iter('''line1
... line2
... line3'''.splitlines())
>>> 
>>> line = next(fake_file) # mimics your call to readline
>>> line
'line1'
>>> for line in fake_file:
...     print(line)
... 
line2
line3
>>> for line in fake_file:
...     print(line)
...
>>> # empty
```